# Eclipse RCP plugin - ActivatorClass

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, activator

I am new with Eclipse RCP and I am working on a plugin where I should decouple application logic from User interface and create two new plugins :

1. Plugin one is for classes defining application logic.
2. Plugin two is for classes defining user interface.

There was an images folder on the original plugin and I put it in the UI plugin. Now, I found out that these images were loaded using the Activator Class which I put in the application logic plugin.
My problem now is how to load these classes from the UI plugin. Should I create an Activator Class for this plugin ? Is it safe to do it ?

I really need help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an activator in any or all of your plugins.

For your UI plugin the activator can extend `AbstractUIPlugin` which has an `getImageRegistry()` method. The `ImageRegistry` can be used to manage images.

The activator for your logic plugin should probably extend `Plugin` so that it does not have access to the UI code in `AbstractUIPlugin`.

Note: when you create a plugin with the New Plugin wizard the 'This plug-in will make contributions to the UI' option controls which class the activator extends.